# Angular: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm following the tutorial of the Material autocomplete (with filter) component with my own array of values, but I hit the following error.

```
core.js:1624 ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at
```

My TS:

```
games: string[] = ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'RPG 1', 'FPS 1', 'MMO'];

  searchTerm = new FormControl();
  filteredGames: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredGames = this.searchTerm.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.games.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

My HTML:

```
<section class="search" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayout="column">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="searchTerm" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredGames | async" [value]="option">
            {{option}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
</section>
```

I've looked around, but no luck. I'm confused since I'm using an Observable. I'm working on Angular 6.

I've also tried to copy the whole example.. but I'm getting the same error there.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error, copy pasted example as well. My problem was a wrong import.
Had:

```
import {startWith} from "rxjs/internal/operators/startWith";
```

instead of:

```
import {startWith} from "rxjs/operators";
```

I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You have `<form>` twice. If you merge the two, it works ok.

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <form class="example-form">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: I saw that when posting the question.. so I fixed that. But I still recieve that error.

Comment: I copied your code into a StackBlitz and it worked fine when deleting the second `<form>`, so what else is going on? - I mean, you code is very reproducible.

Comment: Seems to me it might be something in your Store that throws the error. I took it out of the constructor, because the code you posted does not use it.

Comment: Whats going on? I don't know.. I copied the code from the example and adjusted the array and I hit that error. I will give that Store a try. Thanks.